# decrypting with DES throws an ”InvalidKeyException: Parameters missing” when using other mode than ECB

Tags: java, des, ecb

I basically use the code from here http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-encrypt-and-decrypt-files-using-des.html for an encryption app but I want to be able to chose the mode of operation so I added this:

```
private String key;
private static String algorithmMode;

    public DESCrypt(String password, String algorithmMode) {
        this.key = password;
        this.algorithmMode = "DES/" + algorithmMode + "/PKCS5Padding";
    }
```

the main looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            DESCrypt des = new DESCrypt("12345678", algorithmMode);

            // FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream("d:\\_test.txt");
            // FileOutputStream fos1 = new FileOutputStream("d:\\_test.txt.des");
            // des.encrypt(fis1, fos1);

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("d:\\_test.txt.des");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("d:\\_test.txt");
            des.decrypt(fis, fos);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

As I was saying in the title it works fine with ECB but with other modes I can only encrypt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing an IV value for your decryption. You need to include this in your `Cipher.init` call:

```
... Cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT, someKey, new IvParameterSpec(eightByteValue));
```

If you omit it from your encryption code, a random IV value will be generated. You will need to store this (retrieved via `Cipher.getIV()`) to use in your decryption code.

Comment: how would i transmit the IV? can i just bang it onto the byte array unencrypted?

Comment: @rmalchow: A normal practice to tranmit the IV is the prefix it to the ciphertext, then encode the entire byte[] with Base64 encoding. IV does not need to be encrypted while transmitting. See [aes128-cbc](https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmlenc-core-20021210/Overview.html#aes128-cbc) for an example of passing IV in plaintext.